# Showing one row only for rows with same order_id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently i have this query:

```
SELECT refnumbers.order_id FROM orders INNER JOIN refnumbers ON (refnumbers.order_id = orders.ID)
WHERE refnumbers.refno LIKE '%MAGT-%'
```

This return 24 rows, from the refnumbers. I would like it to make it group by(?), so it returns only one row, if there's 4 rows with the same order_id.

Example it shows like this now:

```
OrderID: 2
OrderID: 2
OrderID: 2
OrderID: 3
OrderID: 3
```

I would like it to return this:

```
OrderID: 2
OrderID: 3
```

Comment: If you want to group by, just append `GROUP BY refnumbers.order_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer: add `DISTINCT` immediately after `SELECT`.

Note that this is only useful if **all** you want to return is the order_id. Otherwise (for example, if you want a count of the number of matching refnumbers per order_id) it would be better to add `GROUP BY refnumbers.order_id` to the end of the query.